# Outlier detection on a measurement stream. Decision theoretic, Bayesian approaches?

Tags: bayesian, outliers, decision-theory

I have a stream of real valued measurements $x_1, x_2, \dotsc$ that I expect to be, for the most part, normal distributed with some unknown mean $\mu > 0$ and unknown variance $\sigma^2$. However, once in a while I have an outlier that is so much larger than $\mu$ that it is unlikely to come from the same distribution, and I want to detect these outliers. I also allow for the possibility that $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ may vary (very) slowly over time (hence the windowed approach below).

I have a heuristic solution that works as follows. At step $n$, estimate the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ of the normal distribution over the $M$ latest measurements $X_n = (x_{n-M+1}, x_{n-M+2}, \dotsc, x_n)$, for some appropriate window length $M$. I use standard sample mean and sample variance estimators for this. Then use these estimates, say $\hat \mu_n$ and $\hat \sigma_n^2$, to compute the log likelihood

$$y_n = \ln p(X_n | \hat \mu_n, \hat \sigma_n^2)$$

over the same window. Now, if $x_n$ is one of the rare outliers, then the data $X_n$ will be poorly fit by a gaussian hypothesis, and hence $y_n$ will be significantly smaller than $y_{n-1}$. I use something like a simple threshold to detect this, and discard $x_n$ as an outlier. (I also discard it from the measurement stream, so that it is not included in upcoming parameter estimates.)

The above seems to work fine, but I would prefer something with more precise underpinnings. I have tried to formulate it as a decision theory problem. Basically, I consider the observations to be divided into two classes $C_1 = \text{"normal"}$ and $C_2 = \text{"outlier"}$. Then the optimal decision rule (in the sense of fewest misclassifications) is the one that assigns $x$ to $C_1$ if $p(C_1 | x) > p(C_2 | x)$ (see for example Bishop's PRML, section 1.5.1). There are two issues with that approach here though:

1. I am trying to infer $p(x | C_1)$ and classify observations simultaneously, but the classification affects the inference, leading to a circularity issue.
2. I have no model of $p(x | C_2)$, so I cannot use Bayes' rule to evaluate $p(C_1 | x)$ and $p(C_2 | x)$. I only know that $\mathrm E[x | C_2] > \mathrm E[x | C_1] = \mu$, and that the prior $p(C_2)$ is small.

If $x$ were a discrete variable, then I could have used $p(x | C_2) = 1 - p(x | C_1)$ to overcome the second issue, but alas.

I have also considered a fully Bayesian treatment, with some prior $p(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2, \mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ for the parameters of the two classes (now supposing that $p(x |C_2)$ is gaussian as well). The prior could, in principle, encode the requirement $\mu_1 < \mu_2$, and I think we could (again in principle) integrate over the parameters, conditioned on the data, to obtain $p(x_n \in C_1 | X_n)$. In reality, however, I suspect this will be difficult.

What standard approaches are there to this sort of problem? Can any of my ideas be salvaged? What would you suggest? Ideally I would like to keep it simple.

Comment: There are very many standard approaches.  They are discussed in the literature on *quality control.*  What really matters are the costs to you of (a) failing to identify an outlier ("out of control condition") and (b) incorrectly identifying ordinary data as outliers.  Another issue concerns the correlation structure of your data, if they are not independent.  If they are not independent, you also need to allow for the possibility that outliers occur in bursts.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for good litterature on the theory of quality control, i.e. not just recipes?

I did briefly consider adding a cost function to quantify the cost of misclassifications, but I just run into the same problems as in the decision theoretic approach described in the question.

Comment: As for a good reference for outlier detection in the Gaussian linear model, there's a chapter by Guttman & Peña in the [Third Valencia Proceedings](https://search.worldcat.org/title/18780626) who show that the change in the marginal posterior of $\beta$ serves as a diagnostic for influence, while the change in the marginal posterior of $\sigma^2$ serves as diagnostic for [outlyingness](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/350775).

Comment: You may benefit from reading Chapter 8 of Sivia's book: [link](https://www.amazon.com/Data-Analysis-Bayesian-Devinderjit-Sivia/dp/0198568320/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1K8KV0OO6583L&keywords=sivia+skilling&qid=1702376605&s=books&sprefix=sivia+skilling%2Cstripbooks-intl-ship%2C168&sr=1-1).

Comment: Durden, thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I don't seem to have any way to access the Third Valencia Proceedings without paying a very steep price.

Romke Bontekoe, thank you for suggesting Sivia's book. The suggested chapter looks promising. I will take a closer look.